# How do you say 'serving' in Chinese as it relates to nutrition?

Tags: food

How do you say "serving" in Chinese, as in 1 serving of vegetables or 3 servings of bread, as it relates to nutrition? If you could give an example sentence too then that would be great! Thanks so much.

Comment: find 19 example sentences with "servings of " at jukuu

Answer (score 2):

If it is restaurant food or fast food, you can use either '份' or the corresponding count word (量词). For example, 每份套餐, 每份薯条, 每个汉堡, 每份红烧肉, etc.

If it is a snack or drink, we directly use the mass or volume for 'serving'. For example: 每 100 mL 可乐 (cola)，每 100 g 薯片, etc.

Below is an empty nutrition label (used as the standard format) published by Ministry of Health of P.R.C. (中国卫生部). See http://www.gov.cn/gzdt/2008-01/11/content_856260.htm. What you want is the title of the second column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### For macroscopic semantics

```
Q: What is included in this set meal?
A: 一份火腿，两份蔬菜，两份果汁

Q: What else you want to order, sir?
A: 一例番茄炒蛋，一例糖醋排骨，一例果盘
```

You can also just use corresponding unit for each object to express " serving of "

like "一盘水果" "一瓶饮料" "一块排骨" "一条鱼"

#### For microscopic semantics

```
Q: What is included in this bottle of drink
A: 100毫克维生素，10毫克碳水化合物，20克糖
```

Here under microscope, scientific unit is  often used like "gram 克" "milligram 毫克"